# how to install sparkR sql in sparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I am new to spark. I am trying to convert my R program to SparkR for distribution purpose.when i try to initilze the sparkR sql I am getting error.

```
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

Error: could not find function "sparkRSQL.init"
```

How to install the sparkSql in ec2.any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you give more information about how you initialized your session? Sys.setenv, library(SparkR), ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set full path before calling init:

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="<full path to spark folder>")
```